# Possible to denylist individual WiFi AP device, but not SSID?

Tags: wireless

In a situation where a network of WiFi access points all serve the same SSID, is there a mechanism to configure WiFi client devices to connect to the SSID but *ignore* an individual AP?

Specifically, I'm looking at a situation where paid community WiFi seems to have a broken AP and give terrible performance in one region near that AP. I suspect getting the owners to power down that broken AP would improve WiFi performance for everyone, and am looking for a way to verify that assumption from my end by having a device connect more selectively vs. just finding the strongest AP signal.

The biggest question is: **Does the 802.11 technology even work that way**, that APs identify themselves so a consumer device could opt to ignore one selectively? If so, is there a common "advanced setting" that I might find for it in the network settings on a given phone or laptop?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su]. Also, networks not under your direct control are off-topic here.

Comment: Oops, didn't realize the criteria for what's on topic were so narrow. Anyway, I got one helpful answer here and found some more useful at https://superuser.com/questions/1413779/under-what-conditions-does-a-wifi-client-switch-to-a-different-ap-with-same-ssid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the technology makes this possible.  Individual access points have a unique BSSID ([link: helpful Juniper intro doc w/ graphics](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos-space-apps/network-director3.7/topics/concept/wireless-ssid-bssid-essid.html)).

It's up to the wireless client, and its user interface, to determine whether to allow users to block a particular BSSID.

I have encountered a similar problem -- a recently-renovated hotel had a malfunctioning AP near my room.  Unfortunately, none of my macOS laptop or Android mobile devices support blocking a malfunctioning BSSID.  :(  My devices, like yours, would sometimes end up on the malfunctioning AP and all I could do about it was physically move to another location to get my device to change APs.